# Warnings when using ES6/Javascript Modules in the C9 IDE

Tags: cloud9-ide

Is there a way to configure the Cloud9 IDE to not show warnings when using ECMAScript 6 modules for .js files?

[image: Example of warnings]

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

ECMAScript 6 support is in the works and should be in cloud9 in the coming weeks. Alternatively for now you can add:

```
/*global import export */
```

To the top of the file to make the warnings go away.

Comment: Thanks, but I still see the warnings when I add that comment to the top of the file. Is there no way to modify the `.jslintrc` file for the editor? I played around with the .c9 directory with no luck.